# 1983 chevy s-10 engine swap w 350

Tags: engine, chevrolet, transmission, s10, flywheel

I have a 1983 Chevy S10 four-wheel drive the engines been replaced by a engine I can't quite figure out what it is but the question I have will a 350 flywheel bolt up to the transmission on my S10 it is the original Driveline transmission and whatever if not what I have to do to make it match up I have the flywheel off the engine that's in it now

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the engine in it right now a four or six cylinder?

Comment: 6 cylinder it's not the original engine I know that's because I needed to get a new water pump and I looked up the specs for the supposed Engine That was supposed to be in it and ordered that water pump it doesn't fit it's completely opposite but I have a 350 engine I can put in it I just need to know if the flywheel is going to match up with the transmission it's the original transmission

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you would be able to mate the transmission bellhousing to the engine, as I believe they are the same for the V6 and V8. The flywheel will bolt to your engine, so that's part of the problem solved. You'll most likely need to have a special friction disk and pressure plate built which would be a hybrid having the hub accept the input shaft of the transmission and the thickness corrected, along with the correct bolt pattern for your flywheel.

Even if you can fit the transmission to the engine with the flywheel you have, the transmission is not going to stand up to the torque of the 350, as the lower end transmissions weren't built to handle that much. If you want to swap in a 350, you should get a mated donor engine/transmission and not try to cobble the V6 transmission to what you have.

Answer (score 0):

The 2.8L V6 used in this year truck is vastly different from the 4.3L available from 1986 forward. That being said the transmission you have is not compatible with any other engine besides the 4 cyl offered from 81-85. To install the V8 requires a matched eng/trans with proper output mounting for the Tcase. Also you will need to relocate the motor mount locations on your chassis to accept your V8. Adapter kits are commercially available as this is a common upgrade in the 4wheeling community.